# Navigatable kendo-grid in angular

Tags: angular, telerik, kendo-grid, section508, keyboard-navigation

I am looking for possible solution for navigatable(508 Compliance) `kendo-grid` in angular. Since `Kendo-grid` for jQuery already contains that [feature](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/keyboard-navigation). All you need to is to put

```
navigatable: true
```

and it's done.

But seems like Angular version of `kendo-grid` does not support 508 Compliance. So is there any way to achieve this with angular?